# How to resolve 401 after getting (a valid) e-trade api access token?

Tags: java, oauth, etrade-api

I have been following the dated and limited documentation on the E*Trade developer site and with help from some other stack overflow posts.

I am pretty certain that I have retrieved a good access token and secret. I have been following their snippets

```
request = new ClientRequest(); // Instantiate ClientRequest
request.setEnv(Environment.SANDBOX); // Use sandbox environment
request.setConsumerKey(oauth_consumer_key); // Set consumer key
request.setConsumerSecret(oauth_consumer_secret); // Set consumer secret
request.setToken(oauth_access_token);
request.setTokenSecret(oauth_access_token_secret);
AccountsClient account_client = new AccountsClient(request);
```

I also tried with:

```
MarketClient client = new MarketClient(request);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("AAPL");
QuoteResponse response = client.getQuote(list, Boolean.FALSE, DetailFlag.ALL);
```

In all case, it returns a 401 code and a message of `<Error>  message>Unauthorized request</message></Error>`

Is this something on the E-Trade end? Or something with my implementation of their snippets? I have reached out to E-Trade but thought I'd post here with the hope of a resolution.

Comment: Are you using v0 or v1? v0 was sunset on 12/31/2018.

Comment: Thanks @ordonezalex, afaik it's v1 - I followed the info on their site a few weeks ago. I actually looked at some python code as well. One app didn't work but then I found a sample ETrade app that did. I then found they posted a java sample app this week that seems quite detailed. I am going to try that and see what happens. I did notice that they updated a lot of the dependencies and also added spring.

Comment: I would definitely follow through with the demo app they provided. I looked through it and didn't see any `ClientRequest` or `MarketClient` like you have in your code, but they probably provide equivalent functionality in the demo.

Comment: Well, we'll see where this goes. The sdk I downloaded earlier this week is indeed V0. Changing the URL the code hits returns a 200 status response. The app just downloaded fails trying to fetch a request token. It is sending the OAUTH settings in the query parameters - whereas the documentation says it should be the header. Looking to see if I can get this newer code working.

Comment: @jaeesle, yes I did. I can't remember exactly what the issue was, I suspect with setting the header information correctly. I have answered the question and added snippets of my code I wrote years ago that I have been using.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot I had asked this question. I was able to get it to work. I do not recall what the particular issue was , or how I resolved it. It is messy! I think it is how the header is constructed and passed along. My code may have extraneous information (eg headers) but it works for me (I can't believe this was nearly 5 years ago)!

Looking through my code and stepping through it, hopefully the code extracted below will help others. I check the response of each request and if it is a 400 code, check to see if the response contains messages about the token requiring refreshing or renewing, and then resubmitting the original request.

```
public void example() {
    String rest_url = "https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list";
    Map<String, String> props = populate("GET", rest_url, new OAuthToken(token, secret)
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String header = auth1.getAuthorizationHeader(props);
    // something like: OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="ac3245e23ba322559b5bdfee47efb9", oauth_signature="40M4xEzHIc%23D", oauth_nonce="NjA0O1O3D%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1704287196", oauth_token="RPb0231x23%22xfdeanIQzC8Lvc6c%3D"
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(1);
    headers.put("Authorization", header);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    HttpRequestBase http = new HttpGet(uri.build(new URIBuilder(rest_url)));
    headers.forEach((k, v) -> httpPost.addHeader(k, v));
    http.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "None");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(http);
    // need to handle token_rejected -> renew -> re-execute  request
}


public Map populate(String method, String uri, OAuthToken oAuthToken)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, GeneralSecurityException {

    Map<String, String[]> requestMap = new TreeMap<String, String[]>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    requestMap.put("oauth_consumer_key", new String[]{SessionData.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY});
    timestamp = computeTimestamp();
    requestMap.put("oauth_timestamp", new String[]{timestamp});
    nonce = computeNonce();
    requestMap.put("oauth_nonce", new String[]{RestUtils.encode(nonce)});
    requestMap.put("oauth_signature_method", new String[]{"HMAC-SHA1"});

    requestMap.put("oauth_token", new String[]{RestUtils.encode(oAuthToken.getOauth_token())}); // URLEncoded UTF-8

    String encodedUri = RestUtils.encode(uri); // URLEncoded UTF-8

    String baseString = method+"&"+encodedUri+"&"+encodedParams;

    signature = computeSignature(baseString, oAuthToken);

    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(requestMap.size()+1);
    headers.put("oauth_signature", RestUtils.encode(signature));
    requestMap.forEach((k,a)->headers.put(k,a[0]));
    return headers;
}

public String computeSignature(String signatureBaseString, OAuthToken oAuthToken, Map<String,String[]> qparamMap) {

    String key;
    key = RestUtils.encode(SessionData.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET)+"&";

    if( oAuthToken != null && oAuthToken.getOauth_token_secret() != null && !oAuthToken.getOauth_token_secret().isEmpty()) {
        key += RestUtils.encode(oAuthToken.getOauth_token_secret());
    }
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    // get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
    Mac mac = null;
    try {
        mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }

    try {
        mac.init(signingKey);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }

    // compute the hmac on the signatureBaseString
    byte[] raw = mac.doFinal(signatureBaseString.getBytes());
    // base64-encode the hmac
    String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(raw);
    return result;
}

public String computeNonce() {
    long generatedNo = secureRand.nextLong();
    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode((String.valueOf(generatedNo)).getBytes()));
}

public String getAuthorizationHeader(Map<String, String> headerMap) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("OAuth");
    append(buf,"realm", "");
    headerMap.forEach((n, v)->append(buf, n, v));
    return buf.substring(0, buf.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this and helping me out.  Using this I was able to figure out how to solve the 401 problem I was having. The Etrade documentation is sorely lacking and their example code has multiple issues so finding someone who actually got it working was encouraging!

Comment: Of course it doesn't help that the Etrade tech support's standard response is RTM.